# Is root beer on topic here?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Specifically non-alcoholic, but I'll leave the title as is in case someone has the same question for alcoholic root beer.

Comment: Good question. [Hard cider](http://meta.beer.stackexchange.com/questions/22/are-hard-ciders-on-topic) has been deemed on-topic for a variety of reasons I wouldn't have anticipated, but in this case perhaps the "overlapping audiences" and other such arguments don't apply as nicely, so I tend to agree with @LessPop_MoreFizz.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Root Beer doesn't really have anything in common with actual beer, other than the name, and a tiny amount of yeast (and with it, from some processes, a tiny amount of alcohol as a result).

And even the name itself was mostly the result of a marketing gimmick by its inventor.

So, my inclination is to say **no** to Root Beer and Ginger Ale, given the *current* scope of the site.